# How to compare and update libraries in local Maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, version, compare

I'm looking for a way to compare then possibly update (i.e. get newer versions of) the libraries/plugins that are (a) used by a given business project of mine or (b) stored in my local repository, against a remote repository.

For example to illustrate use case "(b)", my application has been using some-lib-1.1 for some time. One day some-lib-1.2 gets available. Since my application can use many libraries, I'd like an automated tool that compares the versions of the libraries used by a given project against the ones available in the configured remote repositories. The tool could generate a report such as : "For library 'some-lib', you use version '1.1', newer available versions are: '1.1.1', 1.2'"

Does Maven support this? How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). You can create reports with it. Take a look [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: It seems very close to what I'm looking for. I will check it. Thank you.